# Bootstrap 5 tabs and form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I'm working on an application that uses bootstrap 5. My problem is how to make form item full width inside tabs.

[Display a tab with a form element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGauv.png)

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="d-inline-flex align-items-start">
  <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-user-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-user" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-user" aria-selected="true">Podatki o uporabniku</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-pooblastila-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-pooblastila" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-pooblastila" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-prijave-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-prijave" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-prijave" aria-selected="false">Prijave</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content " id="v-pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active " id="v-pills-user" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-user-tab">
      <form id="posodobi_uporabnika">
      <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-pooblastila" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-pooblastila-tab">Pooblastila</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-prijave" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-prijave-tab">Prijave</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d-flex` instead of `d-inline-flex` on the parent. Use `flex-grow-1` on the `tab-content`...

```
  <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills me-3" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-user-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-user" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-user" aria-selected="true">Podatki o uporabniku</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-pooblastila-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-pooblastila" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-pooblastila" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-prijave-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-prijave" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-prijave" aria-selected="false">Prijave</a>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content flex-grow-1" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active " id="v-pills-user" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-user-tab">
                        <form id="posodobi_uporabnika">
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
                                <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-pooblastila" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-pooblastila-tab">Pooblastila</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-prijave" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-prijave-tab">Prijave</div>
                </div>
  </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/87iE01EIZF)